# Dynamic Java Variable Naming

Tags: java, variables, dynamic

This question is more for furthering my knowledge than anything...

Does Java have anything similar to PHP's ability to generate a variable name?  I have an SCJA Cert and I'm studying for the SCJP and have never seen this, but was curious.

PHP Example

```
$application->{$request->getParameter("methodCall")}($request->getParameter('value'));
```

Does Java have anything similar?  I've been reading on here and the general answer is to use a HashMap which I'm not interested in since this isn't to solve a real problem.  I'm more interested in the is this possible solution?  If not so be it, but just trying to expand my knowledge!

Thanks,
Jared

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Java have dynamic variables for class members?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596499/does-java-have-dynamic-variables-for-class-members)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, variables (fields and local variables) are statically "created" at compile-time in Java.

Of course memory is only ever occupied at runtime, but how many and which fields an object has is decided at compile-time.

Therefore you can't "dynamically add a field" in Java.

And yes: A `Map` **is** the solution to the problem. "Adding a field" is not usually the *problem* but an attempted *solution* that's appropriate for some languages (usually dynamic ones) and inappropriate for others.

Comment: +1 particularly for saying adding a field is not the problem but maybe one solution

Comment: Thanks much!  I'm familiar with HashMaps I was simply curious about if this was possible or not.

Comment: As @Peter commented it *is* possible with some heavy workings (and not really reasonable without third-party libraries), but adds **severe** restrictions, which makes it overkill for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a field in a class. A local variable can only be used in a method.

To generate a field in a class or a variable, you need to generate Java code and compile it or byte code at runtime.  It can be done but is 100x more complicated than using a simple Map. (I have done it dynamically before and I wouldn't recommend it unless you *really* have to)

If you want to do code generation I would suggest using [Objectweb's ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done...Java Reflection only allows you to view the structure of a class but not append to it.