# How to use dynamic variable names?

Tags: java, variables, dynamic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic variable names Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805843/dynamic-variable-names-java)

I'm creating a Sudoku solver / generator in Java. I'm using NetBeans as the IDE. I created an applet and designed it in the NetBeans GUI designer. For the fields (that hold numbers in a 9*9 matrix) i used text fields and i named the variables according to their position in the matrix. For instance, the first one is num_1_1. The first number represents the row and the second one represents the column.

The actual generator / solver will work with a 2 dimensional integer array (int[][]) and when it generates / solves a sudoku it will populate the text vields in the gui with the numbers from the array.

Now, is there a way where i can use say a for loop to loop trough the veriable names and assign each one that way? Something like:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++){
        num+"_"+x+"_"+y = 5;
    }
}
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: As well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/dynamic-variable-names-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192534/is-there-away-to-generate-variables-names-dynamically-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885669/dynamic-java-variable-naming

Comment: As a solution to your problem: use a JTable!

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't, at least not in a way that isn't total overkill for what you want. Don't use explicit vars, use an array of arrays of text fields. There is a reflection API, but that is not called for here.