# Dynamically initialise array name

Tags: java

I am trying to create an array of objects with a MAX_N 6 object into this array, then create another array within an else statement to fit the rest of the array objects.

I would like to name the new array

```
sbag1
sbag2
etc
```

here is my code:

```
public static ShoppingBag[] packIntoBags(GroceryItem[] goods) {

    ShoppingBag newBag = new ShoppingBag();
    GroceryItem tmpObject = null;
    int index = 0;
    String bag = "newBag";
    String bagNum = bag + index;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXNBAG; i++)
        if (newBag.numItems() < MAX_NUM_ITEMS) {    
            for (int k = 0; i < MAX_NUM_ITEMS; i++) {
                tmpObject = goods[i];
                newBag.addToBag(tmpObject);
            }
        }
    else {
        ShoppingBag newBag1 = new ShoppingBag();    
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the arrays? If I understand this correctly you want to name variables dynamically which can't be done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Java Variable Naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885669/dynamic-java-variable-naming)

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to dynamically create new variables in java.
When I look at the signature of your method you don't need to return multiple variables, only an array of ShoppingBags.

You should create a variable of type `List<ShoppingBag>`:

```
List<ShoppingBag> shoppingsBags=new ArrayList<>();
```

each time you need a new ShoppingBag:

```
bag=new ShoppingBag();
shoppingBags.add(bag);
```

at the end convert this list to an array:

```
return shoppingBags.toArray(new ShoppingBag[0]);
```

Comment: `toArray()` should probably be `toArray(new ShoppingBag[0])`

Comment: You"re completely right Lino, I updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Java is a statically compiled language. In general, it is not possible, or to be precise: not helpful to use "dynamic" names for variables.

What you could do instead: use a Map, or even more simple: an array of arrays to hold your data.